# MapInfo Professional 11.5 sample data

Tags: mapinfo

would you be able to point me in the direction of finding a copy of the sample data that comes on the CD's for learning MapInfo Professional 11.5?

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that the MapInfo Professional v12.0 evaluation includes sample data.

There is more information about that version and its trial offer **[here](http://web.pb.com/miprov12)**.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I removed your signature as per the [**help**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behaviour) where it says "Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers."

Comment: @neogeomat: A link to the evaluation version of MapInfo IS the essential part. And nobody can prevent the link from changing in the future, but then www.pb.com or www.mapinfo.com can most likely help.

Comment: @neogeomat - I am sorry, I don't really understand what you're saying?

Comment: @PolyGeo - no worries mate, I was wondering why it kept deleting it, to me its a courtesy and it feels strange and almost rude not saying anything after.

Comment: There's some good material about GIS SE (and Stack Overflow) available in [**Meta**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question) - having a read/watch of (some of) them may help you become familiar with our protocols and why they are in place.

Comment: Cool, will do. Thanks for the heads up.

GIS SE helped me out of a tight spot so anything I can do I will!